# How to make Windows 10 use full resources to do updates?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

The Windows 10 update process takes fooooreeeeever. Is there some way I can make take advantage of full resources to just get it done rather than doing it in the "background" so that it just slows the laptop down for hours upon hours?

To be clear, I recently downloaded the last feature update direct from Microsoft and it took all of 2 or 3 minutes. However, the Windows Update process literally took hours to download it.